# Processing data in one column using split and index based on value in other column pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, split, vectorization

I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to address the following problem

I have a dataframe with the following example structure:

| Split_key | label | sub_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_B_C | 7 | "" |
| A_B_C | 7 | "" |
| A_B_C | 8 | "" |
| A_B_C | 8 | "" |
| A_B_C | 10 | "" |
| A_B_C | 10 | "" |
| D_E_F | 2 | "" |
| D_E_F | 7 | "" |
| D_E_F | 15 | "" |
| G_H_I | 1 | "" |
| G_H_I | 2 | "" |
| G_H_I | 3 | "" |

I wish to populate sub_label with a value that corresponds to splitting the value in Split_key on the "_" character and grabs the correct element based on label. The correct element is the index of the value in label in the unique sorted array of labels that share the same value in Split_key.

The correct end result is shown here.

| Split_key | label | sub_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_B_C | 7 | A |
| A_B_C | 7 | A |
| A_B_C | 8 | B |
| A_B_C | 8 | B |
| A_B_C | 10 | C |
| A_B_C | 10 | C |
| D_E_F | 2 | D |
| D_E_F | 7 | E |
| D_E_F | 15 | F |
| G_H_I | 1 | G |
| G_H_I | 2 | H |
| G_H_I | 3 | I |

My initial attempt is very slow on large dataframes:

```
for i,row in bigframe.iterrows():
    duplicates=bigframe[ bigframe["Split_key"]==row["Split_key"]]
    if len(row["Split_key"].split("_"))<1:
        continue
    if len(duplicates)==1:
            row["sub_label"]=row["Split_key"].split("_")[0]
    else:
        try:
              shift=sorted(duplicates["label"].unique().astype(int)).index(int(row["label"]))
        except:
            shift=0
        if (shift<len(row["Split_key"].split("_"))):
            row["sub_label"]=row["Split_key"].split("_")[shift]
```

Is there any way to vectorize this code in python/pandas? I know using group / ungroup in R makes this possible from a previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` with `factorize` then `map`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Split_key',as_index=False).apply(lambda x :  pd.Series(x['label'].factorize()[0]).map(dict(enumerate(x['Split_key'].iloc[0].split('_'))))).values
df
Out[869]: 
   Split_key  label  sub_label new
0      A_B_C      7        NaN   A
1      A_B_C      7        NaN   A
2      A_B_C      8        NaN   B
3      A_B_C      8        NaN   B
4      A_B_C     10        NaN   C
5      A_B_C     10        NaN   C
6      D_E_F      2        NaN   D
7      D_E_F      7        NaN   E
8      D_E_F     15        NaN   F
9      G_H_I      1        NaN   G
10     G_H_I      2        NaN   H
11     G_H_I      3        NaN   I
```

Comment: I found that this works in some of my dataframes and not in others. Could you explain the reasoning behind the 0 indexing of the factorize() and the x["Split_key"] ?

Comment: To be more specific the numerical order is important for this problem. I think after understanding your solution I have augmented it to include functionality for arbitrarily ordered dataframes

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be clearer if you run it as a for loop:

```py
grouped = df.groupby('Split_key', sort = False)
collection = []
for key, frame in grouped:
    out, _ = frame.label.factorize()
    out = [key.split('_')[num] for num in out]
    frame['sub_label'] = out
    collection.append(frame)

pd.concat(collection)
   Split_key  label sub_label
0      A_B_C      7         A
1      A_B_C      7         A
2      A_B_C      8         B
3      A_B_C      8         B
4      A_B_C     10         C
5      A_B_C     10         C
6      D_E_F      2         D
7      D_E_F      7         E
8      D_E_F     15         F
9      G_H_I      1         G
10     G_H_I      2         H
11     G_H_I      3         I
```